# Majority coloring for directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

I came up with the following coloring concept when studying neural networks (which are often modelled using directed graphs). No idea whether there is already an established name for it.

If $X$ is a non-empty set, we say that $M\subseteq X$ is a *majority* if $|M| > |X\setminus M|$.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite directed graph. For $v\in V$ we set $\text{In}(v)=\{x \in V: (x,v) \in E\}$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. We say that a map $c:V(G) \to \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is a *majority coloring* if the following condition is satisfied:

> For every $v\in V(G)$ with $\text{In}(v) \neq \emptyset$, if for some $k \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ we have that $c^{-1}(\{k\}) \cap \text{In}(v)$ is a majority of $\text{In}(v)$, then $c(v) \neq k$.

We set the *majority coloring number* $\chi_m(G)$ to be the least positive integer $j$ such that there is a majority coloring $c:V(G) \to \{1,\ldots,j\}$.

Many directed graphs I've looked at have majority coloring number $2$, but for instance $K_3$ with the orientation $1\to 2\to 3\to 1$ has majority coloring number $3$.

**Questions**:

1. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is there a directed graph $G$ such that $\chi_m(G) = n$?
2. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is there even a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) $T$ such taht $\chi_m(T) = n$?

Comment: Nice concept, but you should make clear what your question is.

Comment: Right - I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Don't you rather conjecture that every graph is at most $3$-majority-colorable? Which amounts to saying that every graph can be partitioned in $C_1, C_2, C_3$ such that every vertex in $C_i$ doesn't have more edges coming from $C_i$ than from $V\setminus C_i$.

Comment: Thats right, proving this would provide a negative answer to my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me answer Question 2. The answer is in negative: there exists an upper bound for majority coloring numbers of all tournaments. I will not care about the sharpness of the bound.

Let $G$ be a tournament on $n$ vertices, and let $d_1\leq d_2\leq \dots\leq d_n$ be the in-degrees of its vertices (denote the vertices $v_1,\dots,v_n$ respectively). We want to find its majority coloring in $3k$ colors.

Firstly, notice that the first $m$ vertices induce a sub-tournament with $m\choose 2$ edges. This means that $d_1+\dots+d_m\geq {m\choose 2}$, which yields $d_m\geq \frac{m-1}2$. Now we paint $v_1,\dots,v_{2k}$ with the last $2k$ colors; all the remaining vertices will be painted with the first $k$ colors, so the conditions for $v_1,\dots,v_{2k}$ are satisfied automatically.

Each of the remaining vertices has in-degree at least $k$. Consider a random coloring of them in $k$ colors. Now, for each $i>2k$, the probability $p_i$ that at least half of $\mathop{\rm In}(v_i)$ are painted with the color of $v_i$ can be bounded by Hoeffding's inequality as 
$$
  p_i\leq \exp\left(-2\left(\frac12-\frac1k\right)^2 d_i\right)^2
  \leq  \exp\left(-\frac{(k-2)^2}{2k^2}(i-1)\right)
$$
(the estimate may become even better if $\mathop{\rm In}(v_i)$ contains some of the first $2k$ vertices).
So the probability that at least one vertex violates the required condition does not exceed
$$
  \sum_{i=2k+1}^n p_i
  \leq \sum_{i=2k+1}^n \exp\left(-\frac{(k-2)^2}{4k^2}(i-1)\right)
  <\sum_{j=2k}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(k-2)^2}{4k^2}j\right)\\
  =\exp\left(-\frac{k(k-2)^2}{4k^2}\right)\cdot 
    \left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{(k-2)^2}{4k^2}\right)\right)^{-1}.
$$
This last bound tends to $0$ as $k\to\infty$, so it is less than $1$ for some value of $k$. This value fits.

**Remarks.** 1. One may try to improve this estimate by making something different with the vertices of low in-degree, e.g., introducing them into a general scheme and computing the sharp values of $p_i$ for these vertices. However, I doubt that a sharp bound may be obtained in this way.

2. The estimates from the beginning do not work for arbitrary digraphs. However, we may see some conditions a hypothetical example should satisfy.

Firstly, a minimal example should not contain vertices of low total degree, since one may color the graph without such vertex, and then paint it with a color different from all its neighbors' colors. On the other hand, this graph should contain *many* vertices of *relatively small* in-degree, since otherwise the estimate using Hoeffding's inequality would work.

Comment: Lovely answer to question 2 - thank you very much indeed! I'm going to accept this answer after a while (I will be waiting a bit for inputs to question 1).

Answer (score 6):

According to this [link](http://www.princeton.edu/~sspirkl/openproblems.html) (see point $15$), Matt DeVos and David Wood can prove that every digraph in which each vertex has an out-neighbour has a good $4$-colouring (I am using their terminology).

**Update.** The paper [Majority Colourings of Digraphs](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.03040v1.pdf) by Kreutzer, Oum, Seymour, van der Zypen (the OP), and Wood is now available on the arXiv. They give a short proof for $4$ colours and provide evidence for the conjecture with $3$ colours.

Answer (score 5):

The paper mentioned above has been published:

Stephan Kreutzer, Sang-il Oum, Paul Seymour, Dominic van der Zypen, David R. Wood. 
"Majority Colourings of Digraphs"
Electronic Journal of Combinatorics, 24(2):#P2.25, 2017. 
http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v24i2p25

Other papers have appeared on this topic:

Marcin Anholcer, Bartłomiej Bosek, Jarosław Grytczuk. 
"Every digraph is majority 4-choosable"
http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06912

Fiachra Knox, Robert Šámal. 
"Linear Bound for Majority Colourings of Digraphs"
https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05715

A. Girao, T. Kittipassorn, and K. Popielarz. 
"Generalised majority colourings of digraphs"
https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.03780